# Override Text Property to auto trim Textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to override the `Text` property of a textbox to set its value as auto trimmed. For that, I had to define the following class:

```
public class TextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text.Trim(); }

        //Automatically trim the Text property as it gets assigned
        set { base.Text = value.Trim(); }
    }
}
```

But the issue is that it's not working for TextBoxes defined in a design page (.aspx) and it only works for dynamically created Textboxes.

I need such code that returns a trimmed value for all TextBoxes whether it is added dynamically or statically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can create a custom control and use that instead of standard texbox.

Comment: Are you sure that the control that you are using in the markup is this one that you have created? You should give another name instead of TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for solution, but my issue is that I have added multiple textboxes in a page and 10-15 pages of that type in my project and its not feasible to change controls in all pages, so I need to override text property to get or set text value trimmed without changing textboxes in .aspx page.

Comment: Search and replace? It should take you about 5 seconds to update your entire solution and I believe this is the only approach that will work. You cannot override the standard control in markup.

Comment: Cross reference: This was also [posted on the The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/684564/Override-Text-Property-to-auto-trim-Textbox-value)

Answer (score 4):

You should create a custom control and give it a different name.

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TrimmedTextBox runat=server></{0}:TrimmedTextBox>")]
public class TrimmedTextBox : TextBox
{
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public override string Text
    {
            get { return base.Text.Trim(); }
            //Automatically trim the Text property as it gets assigned
            set { base.Text = value.Trim(); }
    }
}
```

After this, open your AssemblyInfo.cs and add the following line at the bottom:

```
 //[assembly: TagPrefix("yournamespace", "aspCustom")]
 [assembly: TagPrefix("WebformsSandbox", "aspCustom")]
 //change "aspCustom" to the prefix of your choice!
```

After this your tool should be available at design-time:

[image]

To call your Custom element in markup code, either draw it from the toolbox into the code or write:

```
<aspCustom:TrimmedTextBox ID="TrimmedTextBox1" runat="server"></aspCustom:TrimmedTextBox>
```

**//EDIT**
I have found another working solution here by [p.campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23199/p-campbell): [Find all textbox control in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112605/find-all-textbox-control-in-a-page)

This avoids creating a custom element at all. What you do is define a helpermethod in your Extensions class:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> FindAll(this ControlCollection collection)
{
    foreach (Control item in collection)
    {
        yield return item;

        if (item.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (var subItem in item.Controls.FindAll())
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you have done this, you can iterate over all your Textbox controls on your page and trim the text:

```
foreach (var t in this.Controls.FindAll().OfType<TextBox>())
{ 
    t.Text = t.Text.Trim();
}
```

You should be able to filter this even more by using `Where(t => t.Id.Contains("someValue")` or whatever you like.

What you deem better is up to you.

Comment: You can use the same name but use a different prefix.