# trying to find an alternative to foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

im trying to write a public function which  can call in all my pages to clear all my textboxes after data has been inserted. i've used it like so:

```
public void clean(Control parent)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent)
        {
            TextBox tb = c as TextBox; //if the control is a textbox
                tb.Text = String.Empty; //display nothing
            }
        }



    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
}
```

however, the foreach is coming up with an error saying

"cannot operate on variable types system.web.ui.control because it does not contain a public function for getenumerator.

can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: @arkascha - my profiles says... im really new to this. suggestions/advice on helping to fix the problem welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

You want to iterate the child controls of `parent`, so use this:

```
foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

---

**Recommendation**

I would also recommend checking if the Control is a `TextBox` too...

```
TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
if(tb != null)//Will be null if c is not a TextBox
{
    tb.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

OR

```
if(c is TextBox)//Check if c is TextBox before using it
{
    TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
    tb.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

(see comments for a good discussion and links about the differences between both approaches)

Comment: Why suggest wasteful `is` `as` route when you already have a suggested the more efficient `as` `!= null` route?

Comment: `is` then `as` is expensive

Comment: @weston: The recommendation is to test if the control is a TextBox, I am just offering a couple of options for doing that. The OP can decide which they prefer

Comment: Fair enough, just mentioning it so OP is aware which is better.

Comment: OK, actually as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/360211) by Skeet, I may be wrong about the performance, but there are other reasons to prefer the `as` `!= null` route. http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/360211

Comment: @musefan - so i used the .controls. no error anymore. however it isnt clearing the textboxes. see update above

Comment: @New2This: You shouldn't edit questions like this. You should post a new question if you have a different problem. I would recommend you post a new question, and rollback this question so that the current answers remain valid

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to filter only TextBoxes. Yours doesn't work because you can't enumerate over `Control` you need an `IEnumerable` typically(not required though).

```
foreach (TextBox tb in parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    tb.Text = String.Empty;
    //or
    tb.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.Control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not enumerable, however, it does have a [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which I assume is what you are after

```
foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
{
    ...
}
```

You could make a useful extension method for better readability e.g.

```
public static class ControlExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<TextBox> TextBoxControls(this Control ctrl)
    {
        return ctrl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
    }
}
...
foreach (TextBox tb in parent.TextBoxControls())
{
    tb.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var c in parent.Controls)
{
    var tb = c as TextBox;
    if (tb != null) tb.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to go:

```
for each(Control c in parent.Controls)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071464/override-text-property-to-auto-trim-textbox-value/20071563#20071563), how you can iterate over all TextBoxes on a page. Note, that this code hsa been written by p.campbell.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> FindAll(this ControlCollection collection)
{
    foreach (Control item in collection)
    {
        yield return item;

        if (item.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (var subItem in item.Controls.FindAll())
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you have done this, you can iterate over all your Textbox controls on your page and ... do stuff, really. As you can see below, you can iterate over all types of controls.

```
foreach (var t in this.Controls.FindAll().OfType<TextBox>())
{ 
    t.Text = String.Empty;
}
```