# asp.net c# optimizing code

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, refactoring

just feeling that i'm wasting loops here = CPU time, and was wondering if there's a way to optimize this code, or just minimize it.

Basically what the code does is, goes trough every controls inside the editOkkInfo control.
checking if the current control is an textbox, if yes, then it will perform some stuff, if no it will jumps to next if-statement. This next statement checks if we have counted 14 times(since i only have 14 textboxes), if not 14, then the loop continues, if counted 14, then the loop breaks.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance, and here is the code, cheers.

```
iterate = 0;
foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctrl in this.editOkkInfo.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        tb = (TextBox)this.FindControl(ctrl.ClientID.ToString());
        tb.Text = dt.DefaultView[0][iterate++].ToString();
    }
    if (iterate == 14)
       break;
}
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your input. especially the casting bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `FindControl`, as you already have the control. Just cast it:

```
iterate = 0;

foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctrl in this.editOkkInfo.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
        tb.Text = dt.DefaultView[0][iterate++].ToString();
    }

    if (iterate == 14)
        break;
}
```

An additional readability improvement will do away with the looping over all controls and the `is` test:

```
foreach (TextBox ctrl in this.editOkkInfo.Controls)
{
    ctrl.Text = dt.DefaultView[0][iterate++].ToString();

    if (iterate == 14)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could use statement like these: foreach (TextBox ctrl in this.editOkkInfo.Controls)

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas - Yes, it will automatically filter by type.

Comment: Even if it isn't a performance improvement, it gets very much readable :)

Comment: ctrl.Text = dt.DefaultView[0][iterate++].ToString();

gives me error, since ctrl doesn't contain a definition for Text

Comment: @Mana - What about it? That's what I wrote in my second example.

Comment: @Mana - The second example is more readable. You will notice that the `foreach` is iterating over `TextBox ctrl`, **not** `Control ctrl` - did you make that change?

Comment: tested your second example, even tough it looks simpler, it does not work, since not every element in this.editOkkInfo.Controls is a textbox. There are some buttons, and some div tags. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: @Mana - Well from your example, where you only do things `if (ctrl is TextBox)`, I understood that to be what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your FindControl() parsing by casting the ctrl variable:

```
tb = (TextBox) ctrl;
tb.Text = //...
```

And, we should know if editOkkInfo.Controls are created by code or declared in aspx page. If the former is true, you can save a reference to such objects in a variable, then using it instead of looping.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ctrl is TextBox)
{
    tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
}
```

this should be enough, you are looking the `TextBox` using `FindControl`, knowing that you have it.So, you can just cast the the control to `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen one faster way to find all controls of specific type rather than looping.
This seems more efficient.
[Using linq to get list of web controls of certain type in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613561/using-linq-to-get-list-of-web-controls-of-certain-type-in-a-web-page)
Hope that helps
Milind

Answer (score -2):

I think instead foreach is better a while, because a while wont check all the controls, until  the amount is 14 (could or not check all the controls, depends!)