# Find literals in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 42 Literals on my web page and their IDs like ltr1,ltr2,...,ltr41,ltr42. I want to change their text property in a for loop.

hereis the html code:

```
<table class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="day">
                <asp:Literal ID="day1" runat="server">
                </asp:Literal></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

c#

```
for(int i=1;i<43;i++)
{
    ("ltr"+i).Text="something"; //I don't know which method I must use, so wrote like this
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are you using master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using master page that time your control didn't got directly from Page.FindControl() method. so you need to go 1 level deep to find control from asp:ContentPlaceHolder id's.

**Master Page:**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server" />
```

**aspx Page :**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="day1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

**aspx Page.cs :**

```
var literals = Page.Master.FindControl("cphContent").Controls.OfType<Literal>();
foreach (Literal literal in literals)
{
     literal.Text = "Your Text";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may load all the literals in a collection using `OfType` and later you can modify their text property.

```
var literals = this.Page.Controls.OfType<Literal>();
foreach (Literal literal in literals)
{
    literal.Text = "Your Text";
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since you have control inside another control on the page, you need to do a nested search for controls. You can try the following extension methods. [Taken from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613678/961113).

First create a class for extension method as:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> FindAll(this ControlCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (Control item in collection)
        {
            yield return item;

            if (item.HasControls())
            {
                foreach (var subItem in item.Controls.FindAll())
                {
                    yield return subItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindAll<T>(this ControlCollection collection) where T : Control
    {
        return collection.FindAll().OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

Later you can use it like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var literals = this.Controls.FindAll<Literal>();
    foreach (Literal literal in literals)
    {
        literal.Text = "Your Text";
    }
}
```

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir, what is the problem/error you are getting ? What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: watched literal while debugging, it's null. can't find the controls(literals) on page.

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir, are you sure you have controls in the page, or do you have all the literal controls inside some other control, for example Panel ?

Comment: yes sure. on page there is a table, in the table every "td"s there is a div. into the divs there are literals. I will add html code into the question.

Comment: @Habib : please asked him to is there using master page or Not?

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir, check the edited answer, I just tried with your table and it works.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Page.FindControl() method?

```
for(int i=1;i<43;i++)
{
    Literal li = (Literal)Page.FindControl("ltr"+i);
    li.Text="something";
}
```

Comment: if you have master page, then you can try  Page.FindControl("YourContentPageHolderName").FindControl("ltr" + i);

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a recursive lookup of the controls on the page.
By performance .net dont to this by default.

Read more about Recursive FindControl [here](http://ardalis.com/recursive-findcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, wrap a  at the top level like this:

```
    <div id="Content" runat="Server">

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
            <td><asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal5" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal6" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal7" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal8" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal9" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal10" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal11" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal12" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td><asp:Literal ID="Literal13" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
```

and you can code like this :

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Literal li = (Literal)Content.FindControl("Literal"+i);
        }
```