# Pass javascript code from asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass some JavaScript code which I build up using String Builder on server side (ASP.NET code behind) to JavaScript on html page. Here's what I am doing.

I do use Master Page and aspx page something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script  type="text/javascript">
// Some initial JavaScript code
// followed by a Literal tag, to be replaced by 
// JavaScript code block which comes from code behind
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="SomeID"></asp:Literal>

// some more JavaScript.
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Then in code behind aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Literal ID = (Literal)this.Page.FindControl("SomeID");
  ID.Text = SomeStuff();
}
private string SomeStuff()
{
  string javascript = "";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("Some JavaScript Code");
  sb.Append("dynamically buildup on server side");
}
```

However the problem is **this.Page.FindContol("SomeID")** returns NULL. It looks like Literal ID is inaccessible when inside **script** tags. I cannot use div or span tags around Literal control, which is inside **script** tags. div/span will leave stray markup inside JavaScript code. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `SomeID.Text = "some javascript";`

Comment: @Matthew your suggestion also works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, are you using a master page? If yes? Its `Master.FindControl()`. Other than that, is there a particular reason why you would want to append? Am suggesting you use the `RegisterStartupScriptBlock()` method or `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` method

Comment: Yup. I use Master Page, I tried replacing this.Page to Master, it didn't work.

Comment: I know you have acceptd an answer, but here is a revision to the master page issue: `Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("someID") as <your control type> where <your control type> is whatever you are casting to such as Literal, TextBox, etc.

Comment: Thanks rommel! I am not sure that the accepted solution would work on deployment. I updated my question, my ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent". Should I use, Literal ID = Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("SomeID") as Literal;

Comment: Awesome! just figured out that the ClientID for my Literal is MainContent_SomeID. So, I replaced ContentPlaceHolder1 with the ID MainContent and JavaScript snippet show up exactly where I wanted it to be. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to assign some script to the literal control from code behind.

As I know in this case, your literal should be in the .aspx page. 
Prepare whatever the string builder in code behind and just assign the string builder to the literal from code behind once your string builder is ready.

```
this.SomeID.Text = SomeStuff();
```

Comment: Funny, it seems to be working (at least not complaining) Null reference. I thought, since on page_load Id name changes for server side controls. I should use FindControl. Thanks, you saved me ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
var literals = Page.Master.FindControl("SomeID").Controls.OfType<Literal>();
// Literal ID = (Literal)this.Page.FindControl("SomeID");
 this.literals.Text = SomeStuff();
}

private string SomeStuff()
{
 string javascript = "";
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("Some JavaScript Code");
 sb.Append("dynamically buildup on server side");
 return sb;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nayeem! I tried your suggestion, But i get error as soon as I type literals.Text ??

Comment: whats value comes in Literals ?

Comment: SomeStuff() returns String Builder which contains javascript code snippet.

Comment: Thanks Nayeem! I think that instead of ID of Literal control (i.e `SomeID`), I should be using ID of master page PlaceHolder which in my case is `MainContent`. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037501/find-literals-in-aspx-page)